# Python - Flattening the nested JSON file

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am working with API data that I pull from the Nobel Prize API. 
Particularly the following endpoints (Nobel API version 2): https://api.nobelprize.org/2.0/laureates 
I have successfully pulled them using a [simple Python Script](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u925hls1e97trft/PlayingWithAPI.py?dl=0) that I build.

Below are some of the example of the JSON file contents. 
But first, allow me to apologize in advance about the length of the snippet. 
I couldn't find a better way to present it.

Type - 1

```
{
    "laureates": [
        {
            "birth": {
                "date": "1943-00-00",
                "place": {
                    "city": {
                        "en": "Montclair, NJ",
                        "no": "Montclair, NJ",
                        "se": "Montclair, NJ"
                    },
                    "cityNow": {
                        "en": "Montclair, NJ",
                        "no": "Montclair, NJ",
                        "se": "Montclair, NJ"
                    },
                    "continent": {
                        "en": "North America"
                    },
                    "country": {
                        "en": "USA",
                        "no": "USA",
                        "se": "USA"
                    },
                    "countryNow": {
                        "en": "USA",
                        "no": "USA",
                        "se": "USA"
                    },
                    "locationString": {
                        "en": "Montclair, NJ, USA",
                        "no": "Montclair, NJ, USA",
                        "se": "Montclair, NJ, USA"
                    }
                }
            },
            "familyName": {
                "en": "Spence",
                "se": "Spence"
            },
            "fullName": {
                "en": "A. Michael Spence",
                "se": "A. Michael Spence"
            },
            "gender": "male",
            "givenName": {
                "en": "A. Michael",
                "se": "A. Michael"
            },
            "id": "745",
            "knownName": {
                "en": "A. Michael Spence",
                "se": "A. Michael Spence"
            },
            "links": {
                "action": "Get",
                "href": "http://masterdataapi.nobelprize.org/2/laureate/745",
                "rel": "laureate",
                "types": "application/json"
            },
            "nobelPrizes": [
                {
                    "affiliations": [
                        {
                            "city": {
                                "en": "Stanford, CA",
                                "no": "Stanford, CA",
                                "se": "Stanford, CA"
                            },
                            "cityNow": {
                                "en": "Stanford, CA",
                                "no": "Stanford, CA",
                                "se": "Stanford, CA"
                            },
                            "country": {
                                "en": "USA",
                                "no": "USA",
                                "se": "USA"
                            },
                            "countryNow": {
                                "en": "USA",
                                "no": "USA",
                                "se": "USA"
                            },
                            "locationString": {
                                "en": "Stanford, CA, USA",
                                "no": "Stanford, CA, USA",
                                "se": "Stanford, CA, USA"
                            },
                            "name": {
                                "en": "Stanford University",
                                "no": "Stanford University",
                                "se": "Stanford University"
                            },
                            "nameNow": {
                                "en": "Stanford University"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "awardYear": "2001",
                    "category": {
                        "en": "Economic Sciences",
                        "no": "\u00d8konomi",
                        "se": "Ekonomi"
                    },
                    "categoryFullName": {
                        "en": "The Sveriges Riksbank Prize in Economic Sciences in Memory of Alfred Nobel",
                        "no": "Sveriges Riksbanks pris i \u00f8konomisk vitenskap til minne om Alfred Nobel",
                        "se": "Sveriges Riksbanks pris i ekonomisk vetenskap till Alfred Nobels minne"
                    },
                    "dateAwarded": "2001-10-10",
                    "links": {
                        "action": "Get",
                        "href": "https://masterdataapi.nobelprize.org/2/nobelPrize/eco/2001",
                        "rel": "nobelPrize",
                        "types": "application/json"
                    },
                    "motivation": {
                        "en": "for their analyses of markets with asymmetric information",
                        "se": "f\u00f6r deras analys av marknader med assymetrisk informations"
                    },
                    "portion": "1/3",
                    "prizeAmount": 10000000,
                    "prizeAmountAdjusted": 12295082,
                    "prizeStatus": "received",
                    "sortOrder": "2"
                }
            ]
        }}
```

The type-2 view of the content has a new "key" called "death". 
It located between the "birth" key and "familyName" key. Below is an example of it.

```
"death": {
                "date": "2009-09-08",
                "place": {
                    "city": {
                        "en": "Copenhagen",
                        "no": "K\u00f8benhavn",
                        "se": "K\u00f6penhamn"
                    },
                    "cityNow": {
                        "en": "Copenhagen",
                        "no": "K\u00f8benhavn",
                        "se": "K\u00f6penhamn"
                    },
                    "continent": {
                        "en": "Europe"
                    },
                    "country": {
                        "en": "Denmark",
                        "no": "Danmark",
                        "se": "Danmark"
                    },
                    "countryNow": {
                        "en": "Denmark",
                        "no": "Danmark",
                        "se": "Danmark"
                    },
                    "locationString": {
                        "en": "Copenhagen, Denmark",
                        "no": "K\u00f8benhavn, Danmark",
                        "se": "K\u00f6penhamn, Danmark"
                    }
                }
            }
```

I am quite a noob when it comes to JSON. 
However, from my understanding, the above JSON file is heavily nested so it will require some form of **flattening** before we could store it in Pandas DataFrame.

This is where I am stuck and I have searched for similar topics on Stack Overflow. 
However, I could not get my head around it. It seems that I could use the `json_normalize` function in Pandas. But, I am not sure what to put on the following parameters `record_path` and `meta`, given the structure of the JSON file.

Thus, would Stack Overflow community kindly help me progress in my learning to use JSON file? 
Many thanks for your time!

(In case I was not clear enough, 
*I want to flatten my current JSON file into the flattened version so I can use it as a Pandas DataFrame.* 
I apologise for this!)

Comment: see https://pypi.org/project/flatten-dict/

Comment: @balderman, thank you for your suggested answer.
Although, the library does not give me the result of my desired flatten dataframe. I really appreciate that you introduced me to this library!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming your first snipped is stored in a variable called `data`, all you need to do is:

```py
import pandas

laureates: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame = pandas.json_normalize(data['laureates'])
```

and it will give you a DataFrame. The issue is that each laureate has list of nobel prizes, so you might want to extract that into a separate DataFrame (otherwise you will end up with a DF with a list of dicts in `nobelPrizes` column)

Comment: It maybe only me - but I think you need to add:
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize 
otherwise the function is not found

Comment: Hi @AnnaSemjén, it probably because you are still using an older version of Pandas? In my Pandas (ver. 1.0.5), just simple `import pandas as pd` still enable the `json_normalize`.

Comment: @Lucaash that one line works! Also, the result is just what I am looking for. However, I do still need to perform another cleaning. If you are interested this is the result of [it](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f7tz4wvmz2hnu5h/Lucaash_Output.csv?dl=0).

Comment: Also, @Lucaash I am just wondering about another thing.
A small part of your code gave me a **weak warning** notification on my PyCharm. 

Especially the following part `.frame` in the `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`. Is this something I should be worried about? 

(To be clear, that your code did the job!)

Comment: @aldy_abe I just added the type-hint do be more explicit about what the output of the `json_normalize` function is. It could be that the type hint is incorrect. Still it is nothing to be worried about.